# vb.netでSplitContainerのPanel内に配置したPictureBoxコントロールの位置をキーボード操作で移動したい

Tags: vb.net

vb.netでSplitContainerの右側のPanelにPictureBoxコントロール(赤色）を配置しています。このピクチャボックスだけをキーボード操作で移動したいのですが、キーボードボタンを押すたびにSplitContainerの境界線も移動してしまいます。
境界線を動かさずにPictureBoxだけを動かすにはどのようにしたらよいでしょうか？

開発環境 Visual Studio community 2017
.NetFramework 4.5.2

[image: SplitContainerのPanel2にPictureBox（赤色）が配置してある]

[image: SplitContainerの境界線が移動してしまう]

コード

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
            Me.PictureBox1.Location = New Point(Me.PictureBox1.Location.X, Me.PictureBox1.Location.Y - 1)
        ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then
            Me.PictureBox1.Location = New Point(Me.PictureBox1.Location.X + 1, Me.PictureBox1.Location.Y)
        ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then
            Me.PictureBox1.Location = New Point(Me.PictureBox1.Location.X, Me.PictureBox1.Location.Y + 1)
        ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Then
            Me.PictureBox1.Location = New Point(Me.PictureBox1.Location.X - 1, Me.PictureBox1.Location.Y)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Me.SplitContainer1.FixedPanel = FixedPanel.Panel1  'コメントを解除してもSplitContainer1の境界線が動く
    End Sub
End Class
```

**----追記----**
kunif様の回答を参考にさせていただいて境界線を固定したままでPictureBoxだけを動かす事ができました。
ポイントは
１．SplitContainer1コントロールのIsSplitterFixedプロパティをTrueに設定する
２．Form1_KeyDown関数に書いていたキーボードの処理コードをSplitContainer1_KeyDown関数に書く

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.SplitContainer1.IsSplitterFixed = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub SplitContainer1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles SplitContainer1.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
            Me.PictureBox1.Location = New Point(Me.PictureBox1.Location.X, Me.PictureBox1.Location.Y - 1)
        ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then
            Me.PictureBox1.Location = New Point(Me.PictureBox1.Location.X + 1, Me.PictureBox1.Location.Y)
        ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then
            Me.PictureBox1.Location = New Point(Me.PictureBox1.Location.X, Me.PictureBox1.Location.Y + 1)
        ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Then
            Me.PictureBox1.Location = New Point(Me.PictureBox1.Location.X - 1, Me.PictureBox1.Location.Y)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

ありがとうございました。

Comment: 解決した場合には質問に追記してしまうのではなく、**個別の回答** として投稿してみてください。

Answer (score 0):

こちらの記事はC#ですが参考になるでしょう。
[【C#】SplitContainerのPanel固定方法](https://imagingsolution.net/program/csharp/fix_splitcontainer_panel/)

> また、マウス操作でパネルのサイズが変更しないようにするには　IsSplitterFixedプロパティをTrueに設定します。

上記記事のFixedPanelプロパティを設定する方法は効果がありませんでした。
IsSplitterFixedプロパティをTrueに設定することだけで実現出来るでしょう。

---

**追記**

質問の最初の Form1 の KeyDown イベントで動作させるには、Form1 の KeyPreview プロパティ を True にしておく必要がありました。

SplitContainer1 の KeyDown イベントとどちらにするかどうかはお好みで。

---

こちらは逆に4つに分割して動かしたいが出来なかった質問の記事です。
この先何か参考になれば。
[SplitContainer上のコントールの上下左右へのサイズ変更](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/56417/26370)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。kunif様の回答を参考にさせていただいてPictureBoxだけを動かす事ができました。上手く動作したコードは追記で質問欄に載せました。